# Android AVD Custom Resolutions Not Starting

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am running Eclipse for Java Developers (32-bit) in Windows 7 64-bit (64-bit Java EE did not want to work).  I connected the Android ADT plugin, and have created 7 emulators for testing my program in.  All have the exact same default settings running Android 2.2, with the only differences being the screen resolutions.  4 of them work (two built-in skins WVGA800 and WBGA864, and two custom resolutions 480x600 and 600x1024) and 3 do not (1536x1152, 1920x1152 and 1920x1200).  I have tried starting them manually from the AVD manager, and I have tried starting them when running a program from Eclipse.  The emulators start up, but stay on the black screen, never even showing the "ANDROID" text on the startup screen.  There IS no startup screen, just black, and no matter how long I let it run, it stays black and refuses to do anything.  I can't find anything anywhere about a possible cause of the problem, and even tried the "adb kill-server, adb start-server" trick, to no avail.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi! i have the same problem with 1920X1200 on Mac. It seems Android emulator does not support such resolution...

Comment: Trying to get this to work on Windows with API 19 and 1920x1200 display. 1920x1080 works, 1920x1200 crashes. There is a a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=emulator&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=-id&id=63594